# IntelliJ "cannot find symbol" for class that is in my Gradle Source Set Dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

I have a class (A) in a package named itest, for my integration tests. I want it to use a class (B) from another package called test, for unit tests. However when I try to run the itest directory I get "cannot find symbol" relating to all references to class B.

When I look at Gradle -> Source Sets -> itest -> Dependencies I can see [project-name]:test(Compile), which suggests that Class B should be available to class A.

A collegue has pulled in the code and it works fine on his machine, able to use class B in class A tests. The project also successfully completes in TeamCity CI. This suggests it is solely an IntelliJ configuration problem on my machine.

I have looked at other "cannot find symbol" SO questions which suggests to compile the project. When I try this however it errors out with the "cannot find symbol".

Comment: can you check whether the dependency is loaded before or after that class is built?

Comment: I don't use Gradle, but with Maven you sometimes have to update/reload the dependencies from Maven to IntelliJ - maybe there's a similar mechanism for Gradle. (Or brute force just import it as a new project into IntelliJ.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting my .config folder in the .IDEAC2018.1 folder in /home.

The .config file is configuration for IntelliJ itself.